# Splitting data into an array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

```
public class ImportDoctorFile  {

    public ImportDoctorFile() {
              System.out.println("Starting Cons");

     List<Doctor> doctorList = new ArrayList<>();
            Scanner scanner;
      try
        {
             scanner= new Scanner(new File("Doctors.csv"));
              scanner.useDelimiter("\n");
             while (scanner.hasNextLine())
            {        
                String temp = scanner.nextLine();
                String [] tempDetails = temp.split(",");

                Doctor myDoctor;
                Surgeon mySurgeon;

                if(tempDetails.length == 5)
                {                   
                    myDoctor =new Doctor (tempDetails[0],tempDetails[1],tempDetails[2],tempDetails[3],tempDetails[4]);
                    doctorList.add(myDoctor);
                    System.out.println(myDoctor);                    
                }                
                else if(tempDetails.length ==6)
                {
                    mySurgeon =new Surgeon (tempDetails[0],tempDetails[1],tempDetails[2],tempDetails[3],tempDetails[4],tempDetails[5]);
                    doctorList.add(mySurgeon);
                    System.out.println(mySurgeon);
                }      
            }
        }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.print("Error, unable to locate the CSV File!");

        }                        
    }     
}
```

I am having a problem when trying to load the data from my .csv file into an array and split it up. When outputting the details it skips some of the doctors and miss places the 6th index when creating a surgeon. I have pasted the csv file above.

Conor Murphy    12 Front Road Leeds Telephone   conor@hotmail.com   Surgery      12/05/2016

Carol McKee 79 The Green Birmingham Skype   Cmckee-25   Neurology

Robert Jones    165 Main Street Glasgow Facetime    R.jones@gmail.com    Orthopedics

Mary Shelley    297 Peartree Grove Guildford     Skype  m-shelly1   Cardiology

John Smith  13 Value Avenue Bristol Telephone    +44(0)7987545352    Surgery     12/05/2016

Laura Penny 87 Primrose Way Ipswich Facetime    l.penny234@btinternet.com    Pulmonology

Mark Matthews   2 The Strand Dublin Skype   Matthews-m15     Int.Care Medicine

Ciaran Bell 58 Windy Ridge Folkstone    Telephone   +44(0)8452126984     Infectious Disease

Nicola Johnson  128 Ash Park Coleraine  Skype   Nicky-j123  Surgery     24/11/2015

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your example data doesn't even contain a `,` as far as i can see. And you don't need a FILE fore that. Put your input into a single static string, and work from there. That also helps to put up a [mcve] for us. Beyond that: dont reinvent the wheel. CSV parsing is a solved problem. Take a library that does it for you. Believe me: doing it yourself is **much** harder than you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringBuilder` class

StringBuilder class has the property of converting its content into tokens.
Simply add ',' as the delimiter and you will get the tokens.